# How to turn off moving objects without gizmo or shortcut?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

Can I turn **off** moving objects/vert etc. when clicked and dragged on empty space?
I want to be able to use only gizmo or shortcut, to prevent me from moving my stuff accidentally.

I know I can change threshold, but I'd like to remove it for good.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by disable the Move Tweak Keymap in the Preferences.

[image: Move Tweak Keymap]